# How do I print characters with an index number?

Tags: swift

I am a beginner programmer swift

I have a string variable and need print characters with index 
my code is :

```
let responcsestring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: what do you mean by `print with index`.

Comment: what have you tried?, [this will help you a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `substringWithRange` method to generate a substring for a given range.

For example this will print the first character:

```
let substring = someString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))

print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Swift stdlib `String` type and access it's character array.

```
let responsestring = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
let secondCharacter = responsestring.characters[1]
```

Here's an interesting
[Blog post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html) about strings and their different representations in Swift.

Comment: you are better to use String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) without any casting.

Answer (score -1):

be careful!! func characterAtIndex(index: Int) -> unichar returns unichar (aka UInt16)

```
import Foundation
var s = "alpha".nulTerminatedUTF8.map{$0}
let data = NSData(bytes: &s, length: s.count)

let res = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
for i in 0..<res!.length {
    print(i, res!.characterAtIndex(i))
}
```

prints

```
0 97
1 108
2 112
3 104
4 97
5 0
```

...

```
var s = "♡仿♥".nulTerminatedUTF8.map{$0}
let data = NSData(bytes: &s, length: s.count)

let res = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
for i in 0..<res!.length {
    print(i, res!.characterAtIndex(i), UnicodeScalar(res!.characterAtIndex(i)))

}
```

prints

```
0 9825 ♡
1 20223 仿
2 9829 ♥
3 0
```

not every unicode character can be represented as two bytes long sequence (UInt16)!. you are better to use swift's String type directly

```
var s = "".nulTerminatedUTF8.map{$0}
let data = NSData(bytes: &s, length: s.count)

let res = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
for i in 0..<res!.length {
    print(i, res!.characterAtIndex(i))

}
```

prints

```
0 55399
1 56893
2 0
```

even though the original string is exactly one character long.

```
let s = "".characters.count // 1
```

... you can use an index for characters view to string

```
let s = ""
let idx = s.characters.startIndex
for i in 0..<s.characters.count {
    print(i, s[idx.advancedBy(i)])
}
```

prints

```
0
```

Comment: dear downvoter, please comment honestly your decision